# Identity Insert missing in all relevant SSIS Data Flow Transformation objects?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Am I the only person on this particular planet that is inconvenienced by the lack of **Identity Insert**, missing in all relevant SSIS **Data Flow Transformation** objects?

Only the **Bulk Insert Task** supports Identity Insert, what about elsewhere in SSIS?

Is there a technical change in SQL Server 2008 that makes this very, very limited support for **Identity Insert** in SSIS necessary?

Because of this "little" detail, I prefer to use C# data procedures that call SQL Code wrapped in SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] ON and SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] OFF.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a bit annoying.

You can put an Execute SQL Task before/after your dataflow which sets IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF and wrap it all in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Use OLEDB source and destination objects. That gives you identity insert option support. I agree this is a bad deal for ADO.net objects.